# Sizing a div dynamically depending on the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, knockout.js

I am trying to have the following scenario: a section as a container, and inside different div. These are created dynamically. I am parsing a JSON file and for every name of a person I find, I have to create a div with the picture of that person and the name beneath the picture. So my div contains a picture and a string. What I want to do is placing these divs inside the section/container in a row. Unfortunately I was not able to it so far and the divs are displayed vertically instead of horizontally. Indeed, I have noticed that every div takes the whole row in terms of space. I was therefore wondering what's a smart way of sizing a div in such a way that takes the space enough to contain the picture and the text. I don't want to use explicitly the number of pixels because I find it a bad design. Any help? I can try to put some code but I am using knockouts in order to bind all the info.

```
<section id="picturesSection">
    <div data-bind="foreach: { data: people, as: 'person'}">
        <header>
            <img width="256" height="256" data-bind="attr:{src: person.imageUrl}">
        </header>
        <footer>
            <p class="nameEmployeePos" data-bind="text: person.name"></p>
            <p class="nameEmployeePos" data-bind="text: person.dateOfBirth"></p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I think you can manage div's size by css.

Answer (score 0):

You can add "float:left" style to your divs. In that case the width will take as much as the content takes. But in case your content is too long, it also might take the whole page. In that case you can set the with of the divs in percentages, e.g., "width: 20%" to have five blocks in a row.